# Ports filtering in Android

Tags: settings, networking, internet, router

How to configure port filtering in Android using `iptables`? As it is used by default for filtering in the Linux kernel before version 5.0, and after that `firewalld` is used.

Apparently, you should use the Android network interface, i.e. the `netd` service.

Comment: You can discover open ports on your android using: termux - nmap: nmap localhost

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. There are [some answers about managing ports using `iptables`](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=port+is%3Aa+code%3Aiptables), does any of them help? Otherwise, could you [edit] and clarify the question?